# I am trying to display create date using os.walk() but get error "argument must be string...", etc

Tags: python, operating-system

```
import os
import sys
def get_information(directory):
    file_list = []
    for i in os.walk(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
        file_list.append([i,time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) #[file,most_recent_access,created]
    return file_list
    
get_information(".")
```

The error I get is below:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "main.py", line 10, in <module>
    get_information(".")    
  File "main.py", line 6, in get_information
    a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/posixpath.py", line 90, in join
    genericpath._check_arg_types('join', a, *p)
  File "/usr/lib/python3.8/genericpath.py", line 152, in _check_arg_types
    raise TypeError(f'{funcname}() argument must be str, bytes, or '
TypeError: join() argument must be str, bytes, or os.PathLike object, not 'tuple'


** Process exited - Return Code: 1 **
```

I am new to python and StackOverflow and don't understand the answers to related os.walk questions.
This same code above works with os.listdir() but not if I just substitute os.walk. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

`os.walk()` returns a 3-tuple for the directory you pass it and each subdirectory of it, recursively, consisting of the directory, its subdirectories, and the files in that directory.

Therefore you are likely looking for the first element of this tuple, so your for-loop should look something like this:

```py
for i in os.walk(directory):
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i[0]))
        file_list.append([i[0],time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) #[file,most_recent_access,created]
```

Answer (score 0):

Instead of:

```
for i in os.walk(directory):
    a = os.stat(os.path.join(directory,i))
    file_list.append([i,time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)]) #[file,most_recent_access,created]
```

Try:

```
for (dirpath, dirnames, filenames) in os.walk(directory):
    for i in filenames:
        a = os.stat(os.path.join(dirpath,i))
        file_list.append([i,time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)])
```

As @etnguyen03 says, `os.walk()` returns a 3-tuple unlike `os.listdir()`.

If you need the path names in the `file_list` rather than just the file names, the last line becomes:

```
file_list.append([os.path.join(dirpath,i),time.ctime(a.st_atime),time.ctime(a.st_ctime)])
```